# demerge the values between merged cells

Tags: xslt

Can someone help me  with the below xslt issue.

I have table with 5 rows.
First 3 cells(1,2,3) are merged and first cell has value.
Next 2 cells(4,5) are merged and  fourth cell has value.

In this case my xslt is working fine for the sample input.ie) if the cells are merged and its first cell has value then the xslt is working.

But incase if fourth cell dont have any value then xslt is not working fine.

how to find how many cells are merged together?
If rowspan =3 then three cells are merged. Also if rowspan=0 then this cell is merged with previous row.

If rowapsn=1 then cell is not merged.

Also if rowmerged='T' then the cell is merged and rowmerged='F' means cell is not merged

### Sample input:

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 1</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">sample 1</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T" rowspan="3" >1</price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
     <title rowmerge="F">Title 1</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">sample 1</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T" rowspan="0"></price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 3</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 3</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T" rowspan="0"></price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="T">Title 4</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">sample 4</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T" rowspan="2"></price>
    <year >1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title rowmerge="T"></title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 5</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T" rowspan="0"></price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  </catalog>
```

### Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
<artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="3">1</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
<artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0">1</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F">Title 3</title>
<artist rowmerge="F">Sample 3</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0">1</price>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F">Title 4</title>
<artist rowmerge="F">sample 4</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="2"/>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F"/>
<artist rowmerge="F">Sample 5</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0"/>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

### tried with below xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@rowmerge='T'][not(normalize-space())] [@rowspan= 0] ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="(../preceding-sibling::*/*[name() = name(current())][normalize-space()])[last()]/node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@rowmerge[. = 'T']">
        <xsl:attribute name="rowmerge">F</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### What i am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
<artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="3">1</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
<artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0">1</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F">Title 3</title>
<artist rowmerge="F">Sample 3</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0">1</price>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F">Title 4</title>
<artist rowmerge="F">sample 4</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="2"/>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title rowmerge="F"/>
<artist rowmerge="F">Sample 5</artist>
<price rowmerge="F" rowspan="0">1</price>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a small change to one of your predicates:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@rowmerge='T'][not(normalize-space())] [@rowspan= 0] ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="(../preceding-sibling::*/*[name() = name(current())]
                                                        [@rowspan != 0])[last()]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I've changed the `[normalize-space()]` to `[@rowspan != 0]` - the "head" cell for this span is not necessarily the nearest preceding one with a non-empty value, but it will always be the nearest preceding one with a non-zero `rowspan`.

(I've also removed the redundant `/node()` from the end of the `value-of`).